# Dovecot Authentication failed if trying login with @domain

Tags: authentication, centos, imap, dovecot

When I try to test my IMAP server functionality using telnet I encounter the following error.

If during the test i omit the @domain.ex everything works fine(as you can see below);

```
a login user password
a OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT 
SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL 
CATENATE UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC 
ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS SPECIAL-USE BINARY MOVE] Logged in
```

if I try using username@domain.ex. I receive the following error:

```
a login user@domain.ex
a NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
```

Someone knows where i'm mistaking ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, some servers just expect the underlying username.  That's not uncommon for small unix server set ups.

Comment: Could you please clarify well ?
I'm using a1 login username@domain.ex password but i' m still having the error.

Comment: So don't use the domain. Small unix servers usually want you to just use the username.